# Tetradecahedron / polyhedra in blender

Tags: modeling, python, geometry, geometry-nodes

How can I go about creating a **Kelvin’s Tetrakaidecahedron Cell / tetrakaidecahedron**. I'm willing to try it using Geometry nodes, Python, etc..

For more background on what it is.

Tetrakaidecahedron (Kelvin Cell)
http://soft-matter.seas.harvard.edu/index.php/Tetrakaidecahedron_(Kelvin_Cell)

https://ardentmetallurgist.wordpress.com/2020/07/26/tetradecahedron/

https://zapatopi.net/kelvin/tetrakaidecahedra.pdf

I'm using Blender 2.93.0

[image]

Comment: If you can get your hand on a description of the vertices positions in 3D space, it should be pretty straightforward to instantiate the geometry. I don't think there is a built-in tool to do it though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends which one you want. There are (apparently) lots of regular [tetrakaidecahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetradecahedron). The [truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron) in your main references can be made like this...

[image]

... using the shipped add-on *Add Mesh: Extra Objects > Regular Solid > Octahedron*, radius 1, with a vertex truncation of `2/3`, which you can type in to the field.

Comment: I'll edit the question it was the Tetrakaidecahedron (Kelvin Cell)

http://soft-matter.seas.harvard.edu/index.php/Tetrakaidecahedron_(Kelvin_Cell)

Comment: Are you after the curved surfaces then? If not, we're there, aren't we?

Comment: Do like a wiki link.   _"There are 1,496,225,352 topologically distinct convex tetradecahedra,"_

Comment: @batFINGER Hmmm. Yes.         That's  quite a few.      Well. I'd better get down to it, if I'm going to earn that little green tick. Unless, of course, you can knock up a quick script?

Comment: More a "fun fact" for your dinner table conversation. Yeah, not bloody likely.  IIRC PGMath is into platonic relationships.  Do like the [Rhombic Triacontahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombic_triacontahedron)